# Why on pc on chrome the spaces between content are ok but on mac on chrome the spaces are not correct

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

I have my local small page and I have two contents and on pc the margins are looks exactly how I want but on mac the styles for the margins is looks like it's lose it. So what should I add to this for work correct. on mac.

This is PC:

[image]

This is on MAC:

[image]

Comment: Seems to have a different font on a Mac, have you produced that margin using a line break?

Comment: @JamesHunt no I didn't

Comment: Try giving it a consistent font between PC and Mac, on Mac the font size seems bigger and it could be what's throwing your content off.

Comment: @JamesHunt yep but what styles should I use

Comment: just paste ur sample code

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to reset settings. Each browser has its own settings, and the best thing you can do is to reset them. I recommend you to first try a simple CSS rule like this:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Of course, use the same font also. In your screenshot, they're clearly different.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a font rendering thing. On the screenshots I see two different fonts and two different font sizes. You should use fonts, that are supported on both systems. Maybe you could try google fonts. Roboto is always a good choice.